# For webSearch in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, barcode-scanner, web-search

I want to Search bar code number in Google as well as other website that client need from my application. please give me the suggestion

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an request to http://www.google.com/search?q=MyKeyWords where MyKeyWords is your search string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use zxing framework in your app [link](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

and modified as per your requirement